# How to make an activity appears in half screen in android

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, size

I have an activity where it has three EditText.
When I insert data in them the soft keyboard displayed and hide the rest EditTexts so i can not see what I am writing.

What I want is to make the activity a ListActivity so I can scroll to see the EditText but i had to reduce the space that the activity take place.

What I mean is how can I make an activity to take the half screen space?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to cope with the soft keyboard covering edit boxes is just to use a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. Example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- Put your EditText widgets here -->

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check how you are doing your layout, because the system automatically scrolls your Activity when you click on an EditText in order that the soft keyboard doesn't hides the field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use scrollView.

Check your manifest what value you have given for following attribute:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

You should give it a try with `adjustpan` or `adjustResize`

Answer (score -3):

Just hit the Back button and the soft keyboard hides